# Why do you use async if you don't promote it to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

I'm trying to figure out how to use async/await in C# in my Asp.Net MVC. 
The main point seems to be that it helps asp.net for releasing threads from the worker pool when you are doing IO (so they can process other stuff). For doing so you have to promote the async/await modifier from the method doing the IO call up to the controller action (you better have just a few layers).

Is there any point in using this feature without promoting the async/await up to my controller ? (by adding Task.Wait after a call to an Async method for instance).

Comment: It *could* be beneficial if you're also basically manually doing the same thing the host system does for asynchronous code, that is performing other tasks while it waits.  That may be fairly complex, but doable.  There's really no magic to async, it's mainly a way to allow top-level consuming code to do other things while bottom-level infrastructure code waits for something to complete.  The host system supports it at the top level, but so can your code.  If, however, you're simply "obscuring" the async operation behind a synchronous one then you're essentially negating the benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes", but using `Task.Wait()` in an action is not a good idea because it can lead to a deadlock situation.

Consider the following from the guide, [Async/Await Best Practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) by [Stephen Cleary](//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt149362?author=stephen+cleary):

> **Figure 3 A Common Deadlock Problem When Blocking on Async Code**
>
> ```
> public static class DeadlockDemo
> {
>    private static async Task DelayAsync()
>    {
>       await Task.Delay(1000);
>    }
>    // This method causes a deadlock when called in a GUI or ASP.NET context.
>    public static void Test()
>    {
>        // Start the delay.
>        var delayTask = DelayAsync();
>        // Wait for the delay to complete.
>        delayTask.Wait();
>    }
> }
> ```

However, if you add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to `DelayAsync()` like this:

```
await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

then you can avoid deadlocks, as explained in the article:

> Aside from performance, `ConfigureAwait` has another important aspect: It can avoid deadlocks. Consider **Figure 3** again; if you add “`ConfigureAwait(false)`” to the line of code in `DelayAsync`, then the deadlock is avoided. This time, when the await completes, it attempts to execute the remainder of the async method within the thread pool context. The method is able to complete, which completes its returned task, and there’s no deadlock. This technique is particularly useful if you need to gradually convert an application from synchronous to asynchronous.

Comment: If I understand well, the answer to my question is "you have to promote it" right ? because of the deadlock problem

Comment: Absolutely yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Task.Wait as it can deadlock or produce an AggregateException. If you need to do this then you should use [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) which is non-blocking.

Generally though, it is safest to use async code end-to-end. The benefit of using async away through the entire stack is that your code will be easier to debug and error handling much simpler.

So **yes**, if you are going to use async/await - include it in your controller and avoid using blocking code like Task.Wait.